# Show Me the Perms - Conditionally Highlight viewlsts.aspx?

Tags: permissions, list-view

Many of my Lists and Libraries do not inherit the permissions of their parent Site.  I'd like to modify _layouts/viewlsts.aspx to conditionally highlight the Lists/Libraries that have these broken permissions, so my users (and I!) and tell at a glance which ones are "special".

My understanding is that I should not open this file in SharePoint Designer, so I should edit 14 Hive\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\viewlsts.aspx directly (after making a backup of course).

Here's a preview of what I'm going for:
[image: Conditionally Highlighted viewlsts.aspx]

As always, any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Wonderlaura did a great [post](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15) on this a while back.  Her approach gives a separate view but at least explains how to get the info.